# url repeating codeigniter and grocery crud

Tags: codeigniter, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, grocery-crud

I have a controller `Admin` and under `Admin` it has it has a function called `Password`. Password is a function created with grocery crud. Everything works fine except for the URL generated after the edit action in the grocery crud part.

Before integration of grocery crud, I have no problems with regards to URL like switching on mod_rewrite and base_url().

```
http://localhost/site/admin/home
http://localhost/site/admin/password
http://localhost/site/admin/report
```

During editing action in the `password` function I got this URL (This is the grocery crud URL):

```
http://localhost/site/admin/password/edit/1
```

After update or success URL part is:

```
http://localhost/site/admin/password/success/1
```

This is where my problem starts. When I want to go to `admin/home` and `admin/report` from the after update or success URL the result is:

```
http://localhost/site/admin/password/admin/home
http://localhost/site/admin/password/admin/report
```

Any help will do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `site_url()` function, then you can simply have `<?php echo site_url('admin/home'); ?>` and `<?php echo site_url('admin/report'); ?>` to route properly.

`<?php echo site_url('admin/home'); ?>` will give you `http://localhost/site/index.php/admin/home` depending on your site configuration. If you use `base_url()` instead of `site_url()`, the index.php segment from the URL will be removed.

Comment: I already implemented `base_url()` and `site_url()` function. However after doing edit function in grocery crud like this one:

`http://localhost/site/admin/password/success/1`

the recent url will become the base_url. And if I want to go the menu Home menu `http://localhost/site/admin/home`, the url is `http://localhost/InformationLiteracyProgram/admin/password/admin/home`